# Magento 2.3.3: Logos in configuration not shown?

Tags: magento2.3

After upgrading from 2.2.3 to 2.3.3 the images in the configuration are not shown, instead, I get the image HTMl as text, see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tw4T.png

system.xml of the module: https://pastebin.com/qpzQECRm

How to fix that?

Comment: attach your system.xml file

Comment: Done, see above

Comment: let me check...

Comment: this is for display image as a tab title,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You Can Simply Display Like This :-**

```
<tab id="meetanshi" translate="label" sortOrder="50">
     <label>
        <![CDATA[Meetanshi]]>
     </label>
</tab>
```